# Set all PDF Fields to ReadOnly

Tags: c#, itext

In iTextSharp is there a way to set ALL fields on a form to read only?  Currently I'm setting each one individually which is a pain like...

```
formFields.SetFieldProperty( "Applicant.Phone", "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null );
formFields.SetFieldProperty( "Applicant.SSN", "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null );
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do something like this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
{
  formFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), 
                             "setfflags", 
                              PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, 
                              null);
}
```

Comment: Will flattening the form do the same thing?  (Just found this property)