# SenderView and making fields read only

Tags: itext, docusignapi

Given this workflow:

1. Our user selects some documents (pdf forms that we fill with data on our servers using iTextSharp) in our software
2. We use the REST API to generate a sender view and navigate them to it
3. The documents may have editable PDF form fields on them that the sender will fill in.
4. When the user is on an iPad and for whatever reason doesn't have a bluetooth or other keyboard handy and has to use the GUI keyboard (our users are on the road a lot) they don't have a command key so can't make use of the keyboard shortcuts in the sender view to easily select all fields and mark them read-only.
5. Desired result: upon sending all non-signature related fields become read-only.

The end result we desire is that after the sender fills in any fields, all non-signature related fields that are left become read-only so that any signers cannot make changes. On desktop or with a connected keyboard, keyboard shortcuts, etc. make this trivial for the user to accomplish on short documents. However, on longer documents or in cases where a connected keyboard is not available, this is not trivial and is actually a bad user experience.

Is there any setting that I've overlooked that would do this automatically? Any particular way of forming the envelope that would accomplish it automatically? When we create the envelope we do assign the signature fields to the appropriate signer using composite/inline templates and tabs collections. That part is working fine currently. We are now trying to add the ability for the sender to preview the document, fill in missing data and send while disallowing signers from editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before uploading the PDF to DocuSign, set the Form fields on your PDF as readonly. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11171956/1219543) for doing this using iTextSharp.

When the envelope is created, DocuSign will transform those Fields as readonly for the Signer.

Sender should still be able to edit the read only fields in the sending experience.

Comment: Excellent, that worked! I had assumed they would be read only for all once set that way. Thank you!