# How to make field again Editable once saving the form by setting the "FormFlattening" property to true in iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, itext

I have used "iTextSharp" for populating the data in a fillable PDF. After populating the data I have set the "FormFlattening" property to true because we need the PDF in the application for review only. We are sharing this noneditable document to another application, in that application we again want to make the fields as editable. Is it possible to do the same? If yes can you please guide me how to achieve this!

## Sample Code For Populating data in PDF:

```
string pdfTemplate = @"C:\DotNetWorkSpace\I9EmployeeIdentification.pdf";
string newFile = @"C:\DotNetWorkSpace\I9Employee1.pdf";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("Name of Employer or Authorized Representative", "Bimal Das Kumar");
pdfFormFields.SetField("Signature of Employer or Authorized Representative_2", "Bimal Das Kumar");
pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", "Bimal Das Kumar");
pdfStamper.Close();
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

This code I have used to populate the data in fillable PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have flattened an interactive form, **you have successfully removed all interactivity** and **there is no way to restore the interactivity!** Hence the answer to your question is:

> No, you are trying to do something that is impossible.

A better idea would be **not to flatten** an interactive form, but to **make fields read-only** instead. Making fields read-only will prevent that other people change the content of a field unless they know how to remove the "read-only" flag.

Since you know how to remove the read-only flag, you can make the field editable again afterwards.

For further reading, go to: [Set all PDF Fields to ReadOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171864/set-all-pdf-fields-to-readonly)

Remove this line (in your code same, you have it in the wrong place anyway):

```
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

Make read-only:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfFormFields)
{
    formFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), 
        "setfflags", 
        PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
}
```

Remove read-only flag:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfFormFields)
{
    formFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), 
        "clrfflags", 
        PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
}
```

Mind the difference between "setfflags" and "clrfflags".